# How to measure similarity of two rectangles' ratios?

Tags: similarities, ratio, geometry

I have two rectangles $R_1=(w_1,h_1)$ and $R_2=(w_2,h_2)$ and I would like to check how similar their ratios are. My first naive thought was this: $\Delta=\left|\frac{w_1}{h_1}-\frac{w_2}{h_2}\right|$. But that doesn't work well when $w\gg h$ or $h\gg w$. I would like to apply a fixed threshold $t$ which lets me determine if the two rectangles appear to have similar ratios, i.e. $\Delta<t$. (And I guess by "similar" I mean anything humans would consider similar.)

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a statistical component to your question, as defined by the CV help center? I'm afraid this might be closed/migrated as off-topic as it is.

Comment: Indeed, I'm not completely sure myself if this a good fit. What would be a better place to post this question? (And can I migrate it myself?)

Comment: I'll flag it presently and it should be moved soonish. Math.SE might be a good fit, but you may need a sharper definition of "similar".

Comment: As currently posed, this is a question about human perception, not about statistics or mathematics. Do you have data about how people have classified rectangles?

Comment: Given they're ratios, I'd suggest that the (absolute) difference of the log of the ratios could perhaps be more useful when the ratios can be very large or very small, at least when compared with more "typical" ratios.

Comment: Thank you, Glen. This does indeed work better. It may actually be what I was looking for.

Comment: Check that the (absolute) quotient of the two ratios is in the interval [1/t, t]. This is equivalent to comparing the logs but may perform faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bunch of rectangles $R_i$, you could extract features $x_i=\frac {w_i} {h_i}$ for each of them. When it comes to comparing any two rectangles $R_i$ and $R_j$, I would use Euclidean distance (e.g. for clustering).

The way you formalize this knowledge of ratio depends on the framework you are using.

Comment: Euclidean distance is exactly what the question proposed, though, and decided wasn't good....

Comment: @Dougal In OP, nor in the comments, I don't see any referral to the use of Euclidean distance

Comment: $\Delta = \lvert \frac{w_1}{h_1} - \frac{w_2}{h_2} \rvert$ is exactly equivalent to Euclidean distance between one-dimensional features $x_i = \frac{w_i}{h_i}$, i.e. $\sqrt{(x_1 - x_2)^2}$.